# Gtalk for Terminal in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, google-talk

Is there a way to log onto to gtalk and have multiple chats open using the terminal?

Answer (score 3):

Try [mcabber](http://mcabber.com/), which should be available through apt-get.

> mcabber is a small Jabber console client.
>   mcabber includes features such as SASL/SSL/TLS support, MUC (Multi-User Chat) support, history logging, command completion, OpenPGP encryption, OTR (Off-the-Record Messaging) support, dynamic modules and external action triggers.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

[Finch](http://developer.pidgin.im/wiki/Using%20Finch) is a terminal client compatible (and developed alongside) [Pidgin](http://pidgin.im/) which can do what you want.

Personally, I use [irssi](http://www.irssi.org/) together with [BitlBee](http://www.bitlbee.org/) which is fantastically practical if you are already using IRC to some extent.